# Display data from two tables - one to many relationship in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have two tables:

```
Table 1 -- rps_users:

id
membership_number
family_name
first_name
email_address
staff (staff column having values Y and N)

Table 2 -- rps_volunteer_score:
volunteer_id
registration_assessor
interviewer
professional_registration_advisor
```

The `id` column in the first table contains the same values as the `volunteer_id` column in the 2nd table.
Each user could have multiple `registration_assessor`,`interviewer` and `professional_registration_advisor` values.The possible values of these columns are `0-4`.

What I would like to display in the browser records with users having value `N` in the `staff` column with a format something like this:

```
membership_number:000
family_name:Name1
first_name:Name2
email_address:a@b.com
Type:Interviwer/Assessor/Registrar/PRA/Moderator(If the user have multuple role display all ie, Interviewer,Assessor)
```

Type column recored based on follwing condition

```
    if( $interviewer!="" && $interviewer <= 4 )echo "Interviewer";
    if($registration_assessor !="" && $registration_assessor >= 2 &&     $registration_assessor <= 4 )echo "Assessor";
    if($registration_assessor !="" && $registration_assessor >= 3 && $registration_assessor <= 4)echo "Moderator";
    if($registration_assessor !="" && $registration_assessor == 4 ) echo "Registrar";
    if($professional_registration_advisor !="" && $professional_registration_advisor== 1)echo "PRA";
```

This is my model function

```
    public function get_volunteers_list($condition)
{

    $this->db->select("u.id,u.membership_number,u.family_name,u.first_name,u.email_address,vs.volunteer_id,vs.registration_assessor, vs.interviewer,vs.professional_registration_advisor");
    $this->db->from(self::$tbl_name . " as u");
    $this->db->join(Volunteer_score::$tbl_name . " as vs", "u.id = vs.volunteer_id","left");
    $this->db->where($condition);
    $query = $this->db->get(); 
    return $query->result();

}
```

This is my controller code

```
    $volunteer_list = $this->Users->get_volunteers_list(array("u.staff"=>'N'));
    $this->data["volunteer_list"] = $volunteer_list;
```

This is my view code

```
    <?php
        if($volunteer_list)
        {
        foreach($volunteer_list as $volunteer)
        {

            echo "<td>{$volunteer->membership_number}</td>";
echo "<td>{$volunteer->family_name}, {$first_name}</td>";
echo "<td>{$volunteer->email_address}</td>";
echo "<td>";(Here i want to display the type of the user)
//Following is the condition for "TYPE"
/*if( $interviewer!="" && $interviewer <= 4 )
{
    echo "Interviewer"; 


}

if($registration_assessor !="" && $registration_assessor >= 2 && $registration_assessor <= 4 )
{
    echo "Assessor";


}
if($registration_assessor !="" && $registration_assessor >= 3 && $registration_assessor <= 4)
{
    echo "Moderator";


}
if($registration_assessor !="" && $registration_assessor == 4 )
{
    echo "Registrar";


}
if($professional_registration_advisor !="" && $professional_registration_advisor == 1)
{
    echo "PRA";


}*/
echo"</td>";
echo "</tr>";
        }
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: But you are retrieving a lot more info from volunteer_score than you show... `u.id,u.membership_number,u.family_name,u.first_name,u.email_address,vs.volunteer_id,vs.registration_category,vs.registration_assessor, vs.interviewer,vs.professional_registration_advisor` you could use group concat in the field you really want and you would end up with a single record with a comma separated list of "type"

Answer (score 1):

The assembled sql could look like:

```
SELECT u.id, u.membership_number, u.family_name, u.first_name, u.email_address, 
GROUP_CONCAT(vs.registration_category) AS type
FROM volunteers_list as u
LEFT JOIN Volunteer_score as vs ON(u.id = vs.volunteer_id)
GROUP BY u.id;
```

and you would get one row with registration_categorys separated by comma